# How to bind data to bootstrap select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

json data:

```
["string 1","string 2","test 07 ","here is test"]
```

and this is html

```
  <select class="selectpicker" id="ddl_location">
    <option select="selected">Select Location </option>
  </select>
```

and here is JQuery code

```
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
     $("#ddl_location").append('<option value="' + jsonData[i] + '">' + jsonData[i] + '</option>');
      }
```

the issue is that

> data is not populated in drop-down list

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: data not populated in drop-down list option

Comment: Have you defined the variable `jsonData` ?

Comment: yeah.  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: You'll probably have to call up `JSON.parse` if you called stringify before. Can you share the structure of object `data`.

Comment: Try consoling `data` and `jsonData` .

Comment: Wasn't data already an array? You are going back and forth by stringifying and later parsing. In your original code you just needed to use data 'as is'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after working around the issue, the solution was :

```
 var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
     $.each(JSON.parse(jsonData), function (idx, obj) {
        $("#ddl_location").append('<option value="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.location + '</option>').selectpicker('refresh');
     });
```

step 1: stringify received object
step 2: use each function instead of for loop
step 3: parse the data using `JSON.parse(jsonData )`
step 4: refresh drop-down list every time you append data to drop-down list using `.selectpicker('refresh')`

Comment: If you would like to reset all options use .html() instead of .append()

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work properly.

```js
var jsonData = ["string 1", "string 2", "test 07 ", "here is test"];

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  $("#ddl_location").append('<option value="' + jsonData[i] + '">' + jsonData[i] + '</option>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" id="ddl_location">
  <option select="selected">Select Location </option>
</select>
```

Comment: you didn't add anything! you just copy the cod?

Comment: I defined the variable and it's working. Just run the code and see if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

remember to append $select.append(data).selectpicker('refresh'); when you don't get data populate in drop down